# pandas date_range dataframe to column headers

Tags: python

Im new to python, and im attempting to create a date_range, convert the date_range to a DataFrame and convert each DataFrame row into a header. I have been perusing through the interwebs and cannot find a solution. It seems a simple problem, but i guess im to new to implement a simple solution. Any help is apreciated.
Here is what i have:

```
duration = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2022', periods=52, freq='W')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': duration})
```

Result:
[RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvwNI.png)

Need code for desired result:

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Bq9e.png)

Comment: How about `df.T`?

Comment: Full disclosure:  I know how to export a dataframe to excel. What i dont understand is taking a dataframe column and changing it to a header (row?) pandas has simple solutions, but this one i cant figure out.

Comment: @Ricardo could you elaborate? Not sure quiet what you mean.

Comment: Let `df_new = df.T`, then `df_new` might be what you need

Comment: Whoa! wtf? i need to study more! @Ricardo amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Reflect the DataFrame over its main diagonal by writing rows as columns and vice-versa. The property T is an accessor to the method transpose().